# Decoding JWT payload in front end?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm doing a project for school with my classmates and using JWT in Spring Security. We have a debate over decoding the JWT payload in front end. Front end is being done with Angular. Oauth endpoint gives back the authorization response as following:

```
{
    "access_token": <access_token>,
    "token_type": <bearer>,
    "expires_in": <time>,
    "scope": <scope>,
    "jti": <jti>
}
```

As far as I know, this is the standard response. The debate is whether we should modify this response to have username and authorities with it. For example:

```
{
    ...
    "username": <username>
    "authorities": <authorities>
}
```

I don't see the necessity because the payload already contains the same information. Also, the payload is just base64 encoded. Thus it can't/mustn't contain any sensitive information already by design. Besides, it seems like a security risk because JWT is immutable but making any assumptions about user roles according to the response body is wrong in my opinion. I can intercept the response and happily make myself an admin before it hits the front end and I would be directed to admin view (of course any further request would be already invalid because of the JWT). I had a thought that would maybe put some extra security in the application. The idea is that you can't make any assumptions about the user and his/her roles on the authorization request. You just get the JWT and make a separate "WhoAmI" request to an endpoint with the JWT, which gives you back the username and roles. This way the front end could compare these values with the ones it got from the authorization server and can instantly detect if these values have been tampered with. If I understood correctly then authorization server should be doing this - it should delegate access.

I would very much appreciate your opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you can intercept the token response then you can intercept the "WhoAmI" response and update it accordingly. I would suggest using https to mitigate request/response interception.

So basically i'll suggest to decode the token in the front end. But for extra security you could also check the authenticity of the token by using RS(256, 384, 512) or ES(256, 384, 512) and provide the public key on an endpoint.

With spring in your AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter configuration define JwtTokenStore, JwtAccessTokenConverter and set access to the token key:

```
@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setKeyPair(new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"), "password".toCharArray()).getKeyPair("jwt"));
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(tokenEnhancer());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED')")
    .checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED')");
}
```

To generate a keystore use java keytool like:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias jwt -keyalg RSA -keypass password -keystore jwt.jks -storepass password
```

With this configuration the front end can request auth.server.com/oauth/token_key and validate the authenticity of the token. So if anyone tempered the response the token won't be valid.